# Flask JWT - getting 404 when trying to access /auth

Tags: python, flask

This is how my functions look like:

```
# authenticate a user
def authenticate(username, password):

    userAuth = username_mapping.get(username, None)
    if userAuth and userAuth.password == password:
        return userAuth

# identify user from a token
def identity(payload):
    user_id = payload['identity']
    return userid_mapping.get(user_id, None)
```

But when i try to post some JSON data to it, it gives me the following error:

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL
>   manually please check your spelling and try again.

What could be the problem?

Comment: How did you defined the `@app.route` and what url are you using to do the post?

Comment: I put `@jwt_required()` above my `get` method and i use the url `http://127.0.0.1/auth`

Answer (score 0):

Do you something similar to :

```
@app.route('/auth', methods=['POST'])
```

inside your file?

Comment: No, it wasn't mentioned in the example i was looking at:
https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-JWT/

Comment: Indeed, it is not needed in this context as JWT_AUTH_URL_RULE sets it already as its defaut url. Could you please post more details about your script and your HTTP status code?

Comment: What other details are needed? Shouldn't i be able to access `/auth` as long as my code contains the lines above?

Comment: After launching the app with the code provided by `Flask-JWT`, I able to replicate the same results as them. Could you please make sure you are sending a `POST` request to `http://127.0.0.1:5000/auth` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try flask-jwt-extended instead. Flask-jwt has been abandoned for years now.